# "You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression." when trying to receive Result of update Searcher running in Background Job

Tags: powershell, jobs, comobject

I need to List all  updates on Windows that are not installed and write them to a file. But if it takes too long there must be a timeout.

I tried to run a search with a Update Searcher Object as a Job and then continue either when it's completed or the timeout takes place.
Then I check if the job has been completed or not. If it did I pass the job to `Receive-Job` to get its result and write it to the file.

```bsh
$session = New-Object -ComObject "Microsoft.Update.Session"
$searcher = $session.CreateUpdateSearcher()

$j = Start-Job -ScriptBlock {
    $searcher.Search("IsInstalled=0").Updates | Select-Object Type, Title, IsHidden
} | Wait-Job -Timeout 120

if ($j.State -eq 'Completed') {
    Receive-Job $j -Keep | Out-File @out_options
} else {
    echo "[TIMEOUT] Script took too long to fetch all missing updates." |
        Out-File @out_options
}
```

`@out_options` are defined, if you should wonder.

The only thing I receive is following error:

```
You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
    + PSComputerName        : localhost
```

By now I figured out that the error stems from calling `Receive-Job`. It seems the job is completing before there is a result.
How do I receive Result from my background job?

Comment: There's a missing comma between `Title` and `IsHidden`.

Comment: Thanks @RichMoss . Corrected the mistake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've run into a scope issue. The variable `$searcher` inside your scriptblock is in a different scope (and is thus a different variable) than the variable `$searcher` in the script scope. Because it wasn't initialized properly the variable in the scriptblock is empty, thus causing the error you observed (you're trying to invoke `Search()` on an empty value).

The usual fix for this would be either using the `using` scope modifier

```
$j = Start-Job -ScriptBlock {
    $using:searcher.Search("IsInstalled=0").Updates | ...
} | ...
```

or passing the variable as an argument

```
$j = Start-Job -ScriptBlock {
    Param($s)
    $s.Search("IsInstalled=0").Updates | ...
} -ArgumentList $searcher | ...
```

However, in your case both approaches don't work, which to my knowledge is because of how COM objects are serialized/deserialized when being passed between different contexts.

To avoid this pitfall create the Update session and searcher inside the scriptblock:

```
$j = Start-Job -ScriptBlock {
    $session = New-Object -ComObject 'Microsoft.Update.Session'
    $searcher = $session.CreateUpdateSearcher()
    $searcher.Search('IsInstalled=0').Updates | Select-Object Type, Title, IsHidden
} | Wait-Job -Timeout 120
```